# Firebase Authentication (multiple types of users)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i am working on a react.js project which authenticate from firebase but i have 3 multiple type of user's in it (super Admin,vendor admin,vendor staff) with different privileges. how can i authenticate them from firebase and get to know this is my venor admin or vendor staff etc  ????  because firebase just authenticate single type of user!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control access via [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) using the Firebase Admin SDK on your own server of through [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Set claims server side for a specific bid with a method like this:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
// The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
// next time a new one is issued.
});
```

Then set up your database with a structure that separates admin and vendor admin content:

```
/
   /admin
      /data for admins here
   /vendorAdmin
      / data for vendor admins here
   /staff
      // data for staff here, or perhaps this data is accessible to all since the admins may need access to it.
```

In the Firebase Console, customize the rules to restrict these locations to those who include the proper claim:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "admin": {
      ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
      ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
    }
    "vendorAdmin": {
      ".read": "auth.token.vendoradmin === true",
      ".write": "auth.token.vendoradmin === true",
    }
    "staff": {
      ".read": "auth.token.staff === true",
      ".write": "auth.token.staff === true",
    }
  }
}
```

This is a simplified example, so you'll have to customize it further to meet the needs of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a `users` table in your database, and every time you sign up a user just add them there as well, using the `uid`.